# Spring boot deploy on Sap SCP

Tags: spring-boot, hana

I need to understand how to deploy a spring boot webapp on SAP Cloud Platform.

I created a basic webapp using https://start.spring.io/.
I only added spring web as module.

I modified the generated pom excluding

- spring-boot-starter-tomcat
- jul-to-slf4j because I found a loop can be created by system

Then I added following dependencies as provided

- slf4j-api
- logback-classic
- servlet-api

I added an empty web.xml, I deployed the compiled war on SCP and then I started.
After more or less 5 minutes of loading, the start fails and if I check the logs, I can't find any error.

Has anybody an idea of how I should proceed?

I even followed this tutorial, https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/28/spring-boot-and-sap-cloud-platform-neo/, without any result.

Java version: 1.8
Tomcat version: 1.8
Spring boot version: 2.1.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that the problem was due to log level too low. It caused the generation of 15 mb log, apparently blocking the webapp start